# Angular Theming at Build time?

Tags: angular-material, angular-cli

Hey fellow coder people,

I'm trying to find an elegant solution to theming our Angular application... but at build time. Separate builds for separate customers.

Anyone have any ideas on how? Ideally would not like to use the `environment.ts` feature of Angular CLI as that would require making copies for dev/qa/prod for all the customer environments.

The other catch is... we use Angular Material.

Basically...

How can an Angular application have global colors across components, and theme Angular Material, at build time? Even run time I guess would be an ok fallback.

Answer (score 0):

- Runtime customization

  - CSS variables var(--main-bg-color) in the themes, but it does not work with all components.
  - Generate multiple themes and lazy load them (I haven't tried it). We can create multiple global styles in the Angular app. Load style for appropriate customer, may be server side render or dynamic css linking.

  "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      **{ "input": "src/customer-a.scss", "bundleName": "customer-a" }**
  ],
- Buildtime customization

  - It's going to be similar to environments file.
  - You will have to create separate file for each customer (theme-customer-a, theme-customer-b etc).
  - Use theme.scss file in the style.scss, which could be default theme.
  - Before build, copy customer's file as theme.scss
  - Instead of creating full theme file for each customer, you can use SCSS variables for themes and just create separate variable files per customer.